# How do you make a sound file play in multiple overlapping instances?

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to get a sound file to play faster in order to keep up with the text reveal in the following code. The sound works (in Firefox, anyway), but it only seems to play one instance of the file at a time.

I'd like to have each letter pop onto the screen accompanied by the popping sound. Right now the popping sound is sort of random, and not timed to play with each letter.

I'm wondering if I need to have multiple instances of the sound object, and how to do that.

I already shortened the sound file as much as I could, and the length of the file is shorter than the `setTimeout` interval I'm using. It just won't overlap multiple copies of the same sound file, for some very good reason that I don't know, I'm sure.

Here is the whole code:

(I tried to [JSFiddle it](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyclopeus/ErLVS/), but couldn't get that to work (I'll save that question for a later date))

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#display        {
                color: white;
                font-size: 150%;
                padding: 2em 5em;
                min-height: 600px;
                max-width: 600px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto; 
                }

body            {
                background-color: black;
                padding: 0;
                margin:0;
                }
</style>

<script>
    var text = "Test String...   1, 2, 3; Everything seems to be working, but the sound is lagging.";
    var charDelay = 40;     // Sets the delay time for the character loop

    function loadText() {
        var i = 0; // Character counter
        var myPud = new Audio("http://southernsolutions.us/audio/pud03.ogg");
        var displayBox = document.getElementById("display");
        displayBox.innerHTML = "<p>";
        textLoop();

        function textLoop() {
            if (i == text.length){                  // This condition terminates the loop
                displayBox.innerHTML += "</p>";
                return;

            } else if (i < text.length) {       // This condition appends the next character
                displayBox.innerHTML += text[i];
                i++;
                myPud.play();
                setTimeout(function(){return textLoop()}, charDelay);
            }
        }
    }   

    window.onload = function(){loadText()}; 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it takes a really short audio file to play 25 times a second. even a sine-wave period will sound like a constant 25hz bass tone at that point; not what you want most likely. aside: don't use extra wraps for events: functions are functions, so you can setTimeout(textLoop, charDelay), and set window.onload=loadText; (not a problem, but good practice)

Comment: The length of the audio file is 10 ms.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying, pull `textLoop ()` out of `loadText()` and just pass the variables as arguments. I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you make the sound loop a little longer, say 1 second. Then, control the sound playing through event listeners so that once the text has finished, you stop the sound playing.

Trying to do it as you're doing it now, you could speed up the sound with how its playing in the audio file. This should give better results. That, or slow down the time out.

Below is some code that I've tested which would let you do it through event listeners. The results are similar to what you had, but if you took your audio file, increased it to 1 second and changed it up to have 24 clicks in there, you'd get the exact effect you were looking for.

**Edit**: I've also updated the below to take into account the comments.

```
   <script>
    var text = "Test String...   1, 2, 3; Everything seems to be working, but the sound is lagging.";
    var charDelay = 40;     // Sets the delay time for the character loop

    function loadText() {
        var i = 0; // Character counter
        var myPud = new Audio("http://southernsolutions.us/audio/pud03.ogg");
        var displayBox = document.getElementById("display");

        // Toggle for whether to loop
        var stillPlay = true;
        displayBox.innerHTML = "<p>";

        // Listen for when it ends
        myPud.addEventListener("ended", onAudioComplete);
        // Begin playing
        myPud.play();
        // Start the loop
        textLoop();

        function textLoop() {
            if (i == text.length){                  // This condition terminates the loop
                displayBox.innerHTML += "</p>";
                // If we're at the end, we want to stop playing
                stillPlay = false;
                // Rather than duplicate code, jump straight into the complete function
                onAudioComplete(null);
                return;
            } else if (i < text.length) {       // This condition appends the next character
                displayBox.innerHTML += text[i];
                i++;
                // Direct reference to the function to avoid more anony. functions
                setTimeout(textLoop, charDelay);
            }
        }

        // On audio complete
        function onAudioComplete(e){
            // Can we still play? If so, play
            if(stillPlay){
                myPud.play();
            } else {
                // Otherwise, remove the event listener, stop and null out.
                myPud.removeEventListener("ended", onAudioComplete);
                myPud.stop();
                myPud = null;
            }
        }
    }   

    window.onload = loadText; 
</script>
```

Comment: That seems to work pretty well. I had to use `myPud.pause()` rather that `.stop()`, but this might be a good technique. By the way, do you have a link to any discussions about 'nulling out' objects? That's the first time I have heard of that and I'd like to read up on it.

Comment: Not to hand, but it's common practice to null off an object once you've removed any event listeners to avoid potential memory leaks. Please accept the answer if it's good for you :)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that was a great idea.